# Compile .proto files on every directory

Tags: bash, protoc

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Makefile
README.md
go.mod
google/
  -> Protobuf dependencies (ignore)
gopb/
  -> Compiled Go protobuf files (ignore)
protoc-gen-openapiv2/
  -> Protobuf OpenAPI depdencies (ignore)
providers/
  - polygon/
    - tickers.proto
    - query.proto
```

I'd like to setup a single command that can find all directories with `.proto` files (except the ones indicated above) and run protoc on each of these, with output going to a directory of the same name under the `gopb` directory. So far, I have been able to create a `find` command that returns the directory names:

```
$ find -not \( -path "*.git*" -or -path "*google*" -or -path "*protoc*" -or -path . -or -path "*gopb*" \) -type d -print

./providers
./providers/polygon
```

Obviously, this is not entirely accurate and I'd like to fix that, but the main issue is that, when I use the `-exec` flag to call protoc:

```
$ find -not \( -path "*.git*" -or -path "*google*" -or -path "*protoc*" -or -path . -or -path "*gopb*" \) -type d \
> -exec protoc --go_out=./gopb/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative {}/*.proto \;
```

This prints two errors:

```
Could not make proto path relative: ./providers/*.proto: No such file or directory
Could not make proto path relative: ./providers/polygon/*.proto: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here because, if I call `protoc --go_out=./gopb/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative ./providers/polygon/*.proto`, it creates the files as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So you want to run `protoc` with all the `.proto` files of each directory?

Comment: _"with output going to a directory of the same name under the gopb directory"_ What does that mean exactly? `gopd/providers/polygon`?

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, to both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Fravadona, I realized that the method I was using to compile my `.proto` files wasn't going to work. So, I moved all my protobuf files that I wanted to compile into a new directory called `protos`, which modified my directory structure to:

```
Makefile
README.md
go.mod
google/
  -> Protobuf dependencies (ignore)
gopb/
  -> Compiled Go protobuf files (ignore)
protoc-gen-openapiv2/
  -> Protobuf OpenAPI depdencies (ignore)
protos/
  - providers/
    - polygon/
      - tickers.proto
      - query.proto
```

and then I modified the command to be this:

```
find ./protos -type f -name "*.proto" -exec protoc --go_out=../../../ {} \;
```

This new command finds all `.proto` files in the `/protos` directory and calls `protoc` on each. I removed the source-relative option which also required some code changes in my imports as well. But, this works for my needs. Note I had to use `../../../` for my output directory because my protobuf repo exists inside of `github.com/myrepo/protobuf` and I want the files written to `github.com/myrepo/protobuf/gopb`.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to tackle the problem, but for `*.proto` to be treated as a glob you need to interpret it in a shell.

Here's how you could do it with `find` and `bash`:

```bash
find . -not \( ...paths... \) \
       -type d \
       -exec bash -c '
           shopt -s nullglob
           for d
           do
               f=( "$d"/*.proto )
               (( ${#f[@]} > 0 )) || continue
               protoc --go_out=./gopb/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative "${f[@]}"
           done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean, "treated as a glob?" I don't understand that bit

Comment: Well, I mean that `find` won't expand the glob in `{}/*.proto`, it will only replace `{}` with the target; that's why you get the error `./providers/polygon/*.proto: No such file or directory` (you would get exactly the same result with `protoc ... "./providers/polygon/*.proto"`)

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without calling into a shell? I'm planning to embed this into a Makefile

Comment: I decided to go a different route on this one but your explanation of globs gave me the hint I needed for that so I upvoted your answer. Thank you for your help.